# Linq: Sort child collection 2 levels down

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how to sort using the Event_Number field within my EventNumbers table.

```
var entries = await _context.Entries
            .Include(e => e.EntryEvents)
                .ThenInclude(ee => ee.EventNumbers)
                    .ThenInclude(en => en.Event)
            .Include(e => e.EntrySwimmers)
                .ThenInclude(es => es.Swimmers)
            .Include(e => e.EventType)
            .Where(e => e.MeetId == meetId && e.LocationId == locationId)
            .OrderBy(p => p.EntryEvents
                .Select(q => q.EventNumbers)
                .OrderBy(c => c.Event_Number)
                .Select(c => c.Event_Number)
                .FirstOrDefault())
           .ToListAsync();
```

I've gone through multiple other posts on this subject and feel that I'm following them but the sort is not working. I'm hoping someone can point out my mistake. By the way, I'm VERY new to Linq/Asp.net. If this query is put together poorly, please let me know. I just know what I have now (other than the orderby) is working...

Edit #2: So I've realized now, as a result of my interactions with @Gert-Arnold, that what I think I REALLY need is to sort my EntryEvents by the EventNumbers.Event_Number field, not to sort the EventNumbers by Event_Number.

The EntryEvents model uses the EventNumbers.Id field as a reference to that table and when I display the entries in my View, I use:

```
@foreach (var e in item.EntryEvents)
{
    <span>Event Number: @Html.DisplayFor(eventitem => e.EventNumbers.Event_Number)</span>
    <span> | </span>
    <span>Event Name: @Html.DisplayFor(eventitem => e.EventNumbers.Event.EventName)</span>
    <br/>
}
```

For reference, my EntryEvent entity:

```
public class EntryEvent
{
    public int EntryEventId { get; set; }
    public int EventNumberId { get; set; }
    public EventNumber EventNumbers { get; set; }
    public int EntryId { get; set; }
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }
    public int EntryTypeId { get; set; }
    public EntryType EntryTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what your model loks like and what exactly you want to do, but the problem sounds like you want to use Sort from Linq. You can provide a function to it describing, how to compare two elements of the list. Look for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sort isn't working unfortunately. When I try the code in the MSDN article, the "CompareTo" method doesn't work because my Event_Number field is IEnumerable with the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to sort `Entries` by the ordinally first `Event_Number` in all of their nested `EntryEvents` collections.

If so, it seems you should select `q.EventNumbers.Event_Number`s and order those. Basically, this:

```
_context.Entries
        .Where(e => e.MeetId == meetId && e.LocationId == locationId)
        .OrderBy(p => p.EntryEvents
            .Select(q => q.EventNumbers.Event_Number)
            .OrderBy(n => n)
            .FirstOrDefault())
```

To check the ordering, you may want to turn to query syntax:

```
from e in _context.Entries
where e.MeetId == meetId && e.LocationId == locationId
let firstNumber = e.EntryEvents
                   .Select(q => q.EventNumbers.Event_Number)
                   .OrderBy(n => n)
                   .FirstOrDefault()
orderby firstNumber
select new { firstNumber, e.Name } // Or some other property to identify Entry
```

If that is not the ordering you expected, I think you have to formulate the ordering differently.

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for. However, when I try this, I'm getting the error that says I need to specify the type arguments explicitly. I've tried code like `.SelectMany(q => q.EventNumbers, (parent, child) => new { p=parent, c=child })` But no luck (I have tried various different versions of this). I hate to keep asking for help on this but how do I specify the types in this scenario?

Comment: That means that the compiler can't infer the generic type parameter of `SelectMany<T>`. But at the moment I don't quite see why it can't. Can you execute `_context.EntryEvents.SelectMany(q => q.EventNumbers)`?

Comment: Same error on that line. The EntryEvents model looks like this if it matters:   `public class EntryEvent
    {
        public int EntryEventId { get; set; }
        public int EventNumberId { get; set; }
        public EventNumber EventNumbers { get; set; }
        public int EntryId { get; set; }
        public Entry Entry { get; set; }
        public int EntryTypeId { get; set; }
        public EntryType EntryTypes { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Well, yeah, it matters. Despite its name, `EventNumbers` isn't a collection but a reference. Edited.

Comment: I'd tried what you have above before. When I put that in, it reorders the entries on my page but not the order of the event numbers for each entry. Here is the result of the test I just ran: Event Number: 88
Event Number: 102
Event Number: 116
Event Number: 66
Event Number: 10
Event Number: 52
Event Number: 38

Comment: That is the direction I started going before you posted this. This is very helpful though. THANK YOU!